# Transforming union types in typescript to bind inner type, instead of all types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How is it possible in typescript to bind the union, instead of unioning all possibilities?

```
type A =
  | {
      str: 'true';
      value: true;
    }
  | {
      str: 'false';
      value: false;
    };

type Transform<I extends A> = {
  a: I['str'];
  b: I['value'];
};

type B = Transform<A>;

const allowed: B = {a: 'true', b: true};
const allowed2: B = {a: 'false', b: false};

const bad: B = {a: 'true', b: false};   // this should be an error
const bad2: B = {a: 'false', b: true};   // this should be an error
```

How do I fix the type function Transform, so ‘bad’ and ‘bad2’ is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) to keep you union type from `A` in `Transform`. TypeScript infers the common supertype and removes your union type, when you write something like this:

```
type AStr = A["str"] //  "true" | "false"
type AValue = A["value"] // boolean
```

Example how you could implement it instead:

```
type Transform<I extends A> = I extends A ? {
  a: I["str"];
  b: I["value"];
} : never

// test it
const bad: B = { a: "true", b: false }; // error
const bad2: B = { a: "false", b: true }; // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8AoKUA+UDeyU4M7ACcAuKAIkIFcJSBubHKANwEMAbKkyiOhgX23RYGKfMTIAzNrmo9hLdhBKTW02Sl51EoSFAAqBZgDtc4gPYEAtgB4AklAgAPYBEMATXLAB8CKHcfO3DzgAfkxsZhIbAG1SUVIAXVkAI0iY+SoEul4oEkMIRggCRGLtaAAhH30jE3NrGE9NAGNTY2AoNlZTAHcIVxIK+Ex2knICDIAaKBSoLigNRGbW9tZOntcAJn6fDGGJKWpJ6eVpOaaW-CnmPqgBoYiyLlJDpX3TqAB6d-sCAnMF87aSSumxu212pGOBymnDG0A0Hy+hV+RSAA)

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the value of second union to `true`, so that `false` is not possible for the type.

```
type A =
  | {
      str: 'true';
      value: true;
    }
  | {
      str: 'false';
      value: true; // changed this to true
    };

type Transform<I extends A> = {
  a: I['str'];
  b: I['value'];
};

const good: B = {a: 'true', b: true};
const bad: B = {a: 'true', b: false};   // now throwing error
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to keep type A the same, I'd only like to change the Transform function.  I added more examples to my questions